# Using Git with a huge 200GB repository?

Tags: git, repository, backup

I'm considering using Git for backup purposes - I want to backup my files to an external drive, then commit everything on the backup drive. That way, I can still access old files if needed. My backup set is about 200 GB.

Do you think Git can handle very big repositories like that? Will the commits still be reasonably fast (by that I mean less than, say, 1h)? Am I likely to run into some limits or crashes?

Comment: No, there are all sorts of files including images and binary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this myself.  Unfortunately, Git doesn't compress non-text files much if at all.  So you'll end up with a Git repository nearly as big as your files, and probably much bigger if any of those binary files end up getting versioned.

Now if you have a couple of 1 TB drives, maybe you don't mind the space it takes up.  But if you don't want to devote half or more of your main drive for backup, but you do want some versioning, the best solution might be to back up your binary files with another program, but isolate your text files somewhere else and keep just those in Git.

Comment: Git normally uses gzip for compression. That won't do much for most binary files (nothing will), but I fail to see how the repository is supposed to end up much bigger than the original files. On the other hand, all your files - binary or not - will be deduplicated. So if you have the same file in two directories, it will only be stored once. If a file doesn't change between two backup runs, it will only be stored once, even if it was moved or renamed.

Comment: It depends on how frequently your binary files change.  Picture having a directory full of pictures taken with your digital camera, and editing each of them.  Git is basically going to store two (or more) versions of each picture.  That'll take up a lot of space in short order.

Comment: That's also what most backup solutions do, until you delete old backups. In a normal git repository that's not possible without rewriting the repository history, but if you e.g. create a new branch without parent for each of your snapshots, you can delete the old ones without any hassle.

Comment: Keep in mind that your repository lives in the root of your "project."  Most backup solutions don't also duplicate your data in *the same folder as the data*.  Git will, because that's what it's designed to do, being a distributed version control system.  Look, I love Git and I thought it would be great to use for backups.  But it isn't, unless the stuff you want to back up is highly compressible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your refrigerator for keeping clothes, who's stopping you?

If you are really fussed about efficiency, why use a version control for backup? You could use something that is meant for such thing.

I can think of [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) for a start.

Comment: Git wasn't made for backups, but the scenario is very similar: You are trying to preserve snapshots of your files. Git is interesting for backup purposes because it automatically deduplicates the data and includes integrity checks. However, as far as I know, it doesn't preserve all metadata of files (certain flags, permissions, ownership and similar). It can also be a problem that deleting old snapshots is not straightforward and would require rewriting the entire repository.

Comment: Yes, Git is designed to preserve snapshots of "changing" files, so that every change is recorded and may be recalled. But a backup hardly includes a case when the files are constantly modified. They may be deleted and new files added, but modifications make a rare case.

Comment: Wouldn't Dropbox cost me more than $20 a month for over 200GB? I'm looking for a free solution is possible.

Comment: But github isnt free either. Free users can only make public repo. Your content will be visible to everyone. In fact, dropbox is free till a limit of 2GB. And the content is private too. After that, yes, the cost.

Comment: I was talking about Git, the command line application, with a local repository on the hardrive itself. I don't want to put my files on an online server (and indeed I wouldn't expect any online solution to be free).

Comment: Well then, if you are just looking to save some space, there are other ways to go about it. File compression being one of them. But in any case, Git is just not made for backup. You may use Git for some of the files that are ever changing and you don't want to save various versions separately, but otherwise, going Git may prove to be more troublesome than doing any good.

Comment: fwiw - I'm using Crashplan and am very pleased with it. It's free for all intents and purposes (as long as you don't backup to their servers), allows you to retain history, and supports (encrypted) backing up to computers of your friends.

Comment: Crashplan looks nice. I think this is what Laurent is looking for. You should write it as an answer, and I think it should be marked as the correct answer to this question.